# Error using IDCT (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, dct

Everytime I run this code the program don't respond and then I get this msg and i don't know what is the problem ?
so can anybody help me ?

Message:[image]

My Code:

```
int main(){
Mat image,DctImage;
image=imread("2.jpg");
cvtColor(image,image,CV_BGR2GRAY);
image.convertTo(image,CV_32FC1);
Mat freq;
dct(image,freq);

imwrite("DctImage.jpg",freq);

int Start;int col=0;int rows=0;
stringstream ss;

for(Start=100;Start>0;Start=Start-1){
    for(int x=Start;x<freq.rows;x++){
        for(int y=Start;y<freq.cols;y++){
            freq.at<double>(x,y)=0.0;
        }
    }
Mat dst(freq.size(),freq.type());
idct(freq,dst);
ss<<Start<<".jpg";
cout<<ss.str()<<endl;
imwrite(ss.str(),dst);
ss.str("");
cout<<ss.str()<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your image is in the same folder as your executable? The program works fine for me. It made 100 image files from the original image that I tested it on.

Comment: Yes it reads it perfectly , the problem is at the function idct when i Comment it it works fine so i don't know what exactly wrong with that !

Comment: `0xC0000005` is an access violation. Compile and run with a debugger to find the location of the error.

Comment: when i comment  " idct " function it goes fine so i don't know why it give me error after finishing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `freq.at<double>(x,y)=0.0;` to `freq.at<float>(x,y)=0.0;` because you feed image.convertTo(image,CV_32FC1); and should expect the same element type.

Comment: I don't know why you said this but i tried and it gave me the same error. so what do you see ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, my bad, sorry. Try to change freq.at<double>(x,y)=0.0; to freq.at<float>(x,y)=0.0; because you feed image.convertTo(image,CV_32FC1); and should expect the same element type.

Comment: @AndreySmorodov Could you put your comment in the answer as well.  Otherwise your answer isn't very useful for future readers...  Thanks.

Comment: Worked and yes i get the idea ,  thank you sir very much